# Connection between Trace of $A^TA$ and eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, trace

I am visiting a course about linear algebra. Our professor proved the equality between the Frobeniusnorm and the Schatten-2-norm. For this he used the following equality for a real matrix A.

$\sqrt{(\lambda_1^2+...+\lambda_n^2)}=\sqrt{tr(A^TA)}$

where $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and $tr(A^TA)$ denotes the trace of $A^TA$. May someone please explain, why this equality holds?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there should be no square root?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I forgot to type the second one.

Comment: Also, are $\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues of $A$ or of $A^tA$ as stated?

Comment: @samabu maybe it was ment that $\lambda_i$ are the singular values of $A$. i.e. $\lambda_i ^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A^{\perp}A$, then this equality helps to prove the desired equality, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) that the trace of any matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues (counted with algebraic multiplicity). This is equal valid for $A^TA$ as for any other matrix.

So it really ought to be
$$
\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n=\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)
$$

Comment: Ah, thank you. I now realize that I copied wrong from the blackboard. That's why it did'nt make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

What You do have though is $$\sqrt{tr(A^{\perp}A)}=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_j²}$$
where $\sigma_j,j=1,...,n$ are the singular values of $A$, i.e. the eigenvalues of $\sqrt{A^{\perp}A}$, $\sigma_j^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A^{\perp}A$ and the right hand side is the $2$-Schatten norm of $A$ by definition. Now choose the standard basis $e_j,j=1,...,n$ and calculate:
$$tr(A^{\perp}A)=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle A^{\perp}Ae_j,e_j\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle Ae_jAe_j\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n|Ae_j|^2=$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle Ae_j,e_k\rangle|^2=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n|a_{jk}|^2$$
using Parseval's equality and the right hand side is the square of the Frobenius-norm $||.||_F$ of the matrix $A$. If $||.||_2$ denotes the $2$-Schatten-norm this shows:
$$||A||_2=||A||_F.$$
An analogous result holds for compact linear operators on an infinite dimensional Hilbert-space that belong to the [Hilbert-Schmidt-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator).